# Handle Dynamic FormControl Input/select Required

Tags: angular

I have an Ngif with a condition that will display multiple input, I managed to make the required work, at the moment my problem is that's i couldn't handle it when it's more than one input, I mean It will check for error let's say for 3 input, as soon as i fill one of the input, it consider the other as filled, I'm missing something but couldn't figure out where to correct it.

Inter.html

```
   <div *ngIf="carac.champ === 'intervalle'">
                            <div class="form-container">
                                <mat-form-field appearance="fill"
                                    class="mat-field-select">
                                    <mat-label>Choisir Symbol Minimal</mat-label>
                                    <mat-select [id]="carac.nom"
                                        [value]="getMinSymbol(carac.valeur)"
                                        (selectionChange)="onMinSelectionChange($event, carac.nom)">
                                        <mat-option *ngFor="let min of minsView"
                                            [value]="min.value">{{ min.viewValue
                                            }}</mat-option>
                                    </mat-select>
                                </mat-form-field>

                                <mat-form-field appearance="fill"
                                    class="mat-field-max">
                                    <mat-label>Valeur minimale</mat-label>
                                    <input id="{{carac.nom}}" name={{carac.nom}}
                                        matInput
                                        (change)="sendMinValue($event)"
                                        [placeholder]="'Entrer valeur minimale'"
                                        [value]="getMinValue(carac.valeur)" />
                                </mat-form-field>

                                <mat-form-field appearance="fill"
                                    class="mat-field-select">
                                    <mat-label>Choisir Symbol Maximal</mat-label>
                                    <mat-select id="{{ carac.nom }}"
                                        [value]="getMaxSymbol(carac.valeur)"
                                        (selectionChange)="onMaxSelectionChange($event, carac.nom)">
                                        <mat-option *ngFor="let max of maxsView"
                                            [value]="max.value">
                                            {{ max.viewValue }}
                                        </mat-option>
                                    </mat-select>
                                </mat-form-field>

                                <mat-form-field appearance="fill"
                                    class="mat-field-max">
                                    <mat-label>Valeur Maximale</mat-label>
                                    <input id="{{carac.nom}}" name={{carac.nom}}
                                        matInput
                                        (change)="sendMaxValue($event)"
                                        [placeholder]="'Entrer valeur maximale'"
                                        [value]="getMaxValue(carac.valeur)" />
                                </mat-form-field>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

And this is the ts code

```
  createProductFormGroup = new UntypedFormGroup({
    famille: new UntypedFormControl(''),
    minv: new UntypedFormControl(''),
    minvS: new UntypedFormControl(''),
    maxv: new UntypedFormControl(''),
    maxvS: new UntypedFormControl(''),
    titulaire: new UntypedFormControl(''),
    uc: new UntypedFormControl(''),
    gamme: new UntypedFormControl({ value: null, disabled: true }),
    serie: new UntypedFormControl({ value: null, disabled: true }),
  });
```

The minv minvS maxv maxvS are dynamic string and depending on the carac.champ it will display or not.

[image]

In the first image I selected the first minvs and it considered that the other are OK and that's is the problem.

Second example :
I selected the last one and it considered the other two okey while they are not selected.

[image]

Comment: You have a FormGroup (Really I don't know if you need a FormArray of FormGroups) but you don't use in the .html. **Has no sense!** use formControl, formControlName,... Material Angular inputs allow it instead use value and selectionChange. check the docs about [ReactiveForms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multiple inputs with the same id. Make your id uniques:

```
<mat-select [id]="carac.nom + '-symbolmin'" >
<input [id]="carac.nom + '-min'" [name]="carac.nom + '-min'" >
<mat-select [id]="carac.nom + '-symbolmax'" ...>
<input [id]="carac.nom + '-max'" [name]="carac.nom + '-max'" >
```

You also have to make each row unique, so add the row index in the name:

```
<div *ngFor="let carac of caracs; let i = index">
  <mat-select [id]="carac.nom + '-symbolmin' + i" >
  <input [id]="carac.nom + '-min'" [name]="carac.nom + '-min' + i" >
  <mat-select [id]="carac.nom + '-symbolmax'" ...>
  <input [id]="carac.nom + '-max'" [name]="carac.nom + '-max' + i" >
```

If you're using mat-table instead of an ngFor, you may also get the index (check mat-table documentation)

Comment: No Unfortunately nothing happened

Comment: Actually, it makes all your columns have different id/names. But you also have to make each row have a different id/names.